# ExoPlayer doesn't show video Warning message

Tags: android, exoplayer

I try to run ExoPlayer demo app on my test device with Android 4.2.2 and Kernel version 3.0.50. Video not showing, but progress bar are moving. In the logcat I always have the same messages until cancel video:

```
05-12 10:58:36.910    9027-9291/com.google.android.exoplayer.demo W/﹕ Warning message AMessage(what = 'omx ', target = 1) = {
int32_t type = 0
void *node = 0x9
int32_t event = 2130706433
int32_t data1 = 0
int32_t data2 = 0
} unhandled in root state.
```

Someone has the similar problems and messages? Maybe not with ExoPlayer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.
Device used other default codecs that I need. In MediaCodec.java function getMediaCodecInfoInternal filter all available codecs by "OMX." prefics. But I need OMX.google. filtering to choose software decoder.

Comment: I don't get the answer! Please explain in detail.

Comment: The problem was in my device. ExoPlayer uses hardware codecs for video playback, but my device doesn't support it. I need software codecs. For this I've changed function getMediaCodecInfoInternal and filtered available codecs by "OMX.google.", not "OMX.".